# Stata- iterate over all values of ID variable, adding values from another variable

Tags: stata

I want to iterate over all values in the ID variable, checking to see if a corresponding variable "present" contains either a `.` or a zero.  If a `.` or a zero exists for all values of the ID, I want to append that ID to a list.  When the loop ends, I want to see all IDs in that list.

This is some pseudocode that doesn't work

```
egen group = group(pupid)
su group, meanonly

local presentCapture 0 

forvalues i = 1/`r(max)' {
    foreach `id' in group {
      {
        if pres == 0 OR '.'  {
                  presentCapture = presentCapture + 1
            }
      }
    if presentCapture = 6 {
        list.append(`id')

}

display list
```

This obviously doesn't do anything-- I'm used to Python, so I'm thinking like that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// some example data
clear
input id present
1 1
1 .
2 0
2 0
3 .
3 .
4 0
4 1
5 0
5 .
end

// for each id count the number of obs
// with present == 0 or present == .
sort id
by id: egen mark = total(inlist(present,0,.))
list, sepby(id)

// mark ids were all obs are either 0 or .
by id: replace mark = (mark == _N)
list, sepby(id)

// create your list of ids
levelsof id if mark == 1
```

Comment: works, and I learned a lot!  Could you explain would sepby and levelof do?

Comment: `sepby()` is an option for the `list` command, it displays a horizontal line separating the id s

Comment: `levelsof` is a command that displays (and stores in `r(levels)`) the different values (levels) of a variable

Comment: They are documented in `help list` (for the `sepby()` option) and `help levelsof`

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it.

```
   gen flag = !inlist(present, 0, .) 
   bysort id (flag) : replace flag = flag[_N] 
   levelsof id if !flag
```

Statement by statement explanation:

`flag` is an indicator for any value other than 0 or missing.

If any `flag` is 1 for an `id`, then all should be.

The distinct values of `id` that are not flagged are shown by `levelsof`.

`!` negates logical values, flipping 0 to 1 or vice versa.

Yet another way to do it:

```
   gen flag = present != 0 & present != .
   bysort id (flag) : replace flag = !flag[_N] 
   levelsof id if flag
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick.  I'm completely new to STATA, so learning all these tricks is incredibly helpful.

Comment: Fine. But as earlier edited by @Metrics, it's Stata not STATA, just as  it's Python, not PYTHON.